# How to use properly setFixedLengthStreamingMode(int)

Tags: java, android

I'm having issues using this function. I get the length(); of the file I need to upload and i get the next error ->

Always more Bytes than expected

```
Exception : expected 589715 bytes but received 589840
java.io.IOException: expected 589715 bytes but received 589840
at libcore.net.http.FixedLengthOutputStream.write(FixedLengthOutputStream.java:39)
at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:98)
at com.androidexample.uploadtoserver.UploadToServer.uploadFile(UploadToServer.java:152)
at com.androidexample.uploadtoserver.UploadToServer$1.run(UploadToServer.java:62)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

I used this for get the size of the file

```
int fixedLength = (int) fileInputStream.getChannel().size();
int total = (int) sourceFile.length();
```

Is possible post an example of a working  setFixedLengthStreamingMode(int) correctly? I can only see problems with this method

Complete code here, yes it's for tranfer a file or some files, can be little or more than 15 Mb each, and some times I get  an out of memory in some old devices.

```
public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {

    String fileName = sourceFileUri;

    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;  
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024; 
    File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri); 

    if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                /*   messageText.setText("Source File not exist :"
                        +uploadFilePath + "" + uploadFileName);*/
            }
        }); 

        return 0;
    } else {
        try { 
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
            int fixedLength = (int) fileInputStream.getChannel().size();
            URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);
            //int total = (int) sourceFile.length();
            // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(fixedLength);
            conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
            conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
            conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName); 
            conn.setRequestProperty("mail", MAIL); 
            conn.setRequestProperty("OS", "1");
            conn.setRequestProperty("LANG", "ES");
            //conn.setChunkedStreamingMode(maxBufferSize);

            dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd); 
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                    + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            // create a buffer of  maximum size
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); 

           bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
           buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

           // read file and write it into form...
           bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  

            while (bytesRead > 0) {
                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);   

            }

            // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            // Responses from the server (code and message)
            serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            // String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

            // Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : " 
            //       + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

            if(serverResponseCode == 200) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        /*messageText.setText(msg);
                        Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this, "File Upload Complete.", 
                                     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
                    }
                });
            }    

            //close the streams //
            fileInputStream.close();
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set it to the total number of bytes you're going to transmit. Clearly you are sending more than that. You haven't shown the relevant code so it is impossible to comment further.

Why the DataOutputStream? You don't need that just for sending a file.

**EDIT:** There are numerous problems with your code.

```
dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd); 
dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                                     + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
```

This is what is fouling up the fixed-length transfer mode. You haven't counted this stuff as part of the fixed-length.

```
// create a buffer of  maximum size
```

You don't need a buffer of maximum size. A buffer of 8192 bytes is perfectly adequate.

```
bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
```

`InputStream.available()` is *specifically described in the Javadoc* as follows: ***"It is never correct to use the return value of this method to allocate a buffer intended to hold all data in this stream."*** Fortunately you can just delete this line.

```
bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
```

Unnecessary, see above. Just use `new byte[8192]`.

```
// read file and write it into form...
bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  
while (bytesRead > 0) {
    dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);   
}
```

Again this is all wrong. It's a misuse of `available()` for a start. The standard way to copy streams in Java is as follows:

```
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
{
    out.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```

It works for any buffer size greater than zero; it doesn't care how long the input is; and it works correctly for the final read whatever its size.

```
// send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
```

Again you haven't counted this as part of the fixed-length transfer size.

But I must say you would be better off using chunked transfer mode and letting `HttpURLConnection` do all the heavy lifting: all you need then is the copy loop above.

Comment: Thank you very much EJP, I have fixed all, and today I'll test with an old device and see if I still receiving the out of memory error :-) I'll say you the results, thanks!!

Comment: when I do this and I upload a text file --*****
Content-Disposition: f... is added to the start of the file and --*****-- to the end

Comment: @EJP  What if the file is very large?

Comment: @EJP  or David. Could you please update the complete correct code? I follow an example which is almost the same as yours on the net. And that tutorial makes several mistakes as EJP describes. Could you update your answer? If it solves my problem, I would ask a new question, and you can get the reputation.

Comment: @Stallman It doesn't make any difference to the code how large the file is. I've already stated that. I don't know why you're asking.

Comment: @EJP  Following your statement, I only have to create a `FileInputStream` called `in`, and the argument is the target file,
and new `DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputstream);` which is called `out`. Regarding to the header setting, use `chuncked transfer mode`: conn.setChunkedStreamingMode(1024);, and finally adopt the `while loop`. Is that all?

Comment: The argument of `new FileInputStream` is the *source* file.

Comment: Well, it can't work. Maybe the server doesn't support `setChunkedStreamingMode`, according to the official document:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#setChunkedStreamingMode(int)
It indicates that some server may not support it. But I think it's the problem of `setChunkedStreamingMode(THE NUMBER)` What does it actually mean? In android development official doc, http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html, if we don't know the body size, it sets the number to `0`

Comment: Define "doesn't work", and "server". I've never used one that didn't support chunked transfer mode. Your link doesn't say a word about it either. You need to post actual symptoms here, not guesswork.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63403/discussion-between-stallman-and-ejp).

Comment: Just try it this way and report the results. `THE_NUMBER` is the size of the chunks. Setting it to zero uses a default, typically 1024. You don't have to know the body size in advance. All this is already stated in your link.

Comment: Well, I got the error message in debug mode. I catch the exception: `sendto failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe)`. Whenever I use `setChunkedStreamingMode`, the error msg appears.

Comment: OK so that means the server is closing the connection while you're still sending. There could be several reasons for that other than chunked transfer mode: for example, you may be exceeding an upload size limit. What is the server?

Comment: `uhttpd`. But as I know there is no size limit for the server configuration.

Comment: I use `setFixedLengthStreamingMode(FileSize + boundaryString);` to solve the problem. `FilSize` is the size of file(bytes) and bourdaryString is the size of string segment which looks like: `boudnaryXXXXX--`. But I still can't figure out why `setChunkedStreamingMode` can't work.

Comment: @Stallman It *can* work, and it *does* work. But if you set it, you don't have to define the chunks yourself: just write the data. Chunking will happen automatically.